# Facebook App Page not found

Tags: android, facebook, submission, review

I am using facebook-login in my android app. Everything works fine I can upload and post images with my android app, but below the posted images is "posted via [appname]". If I click at [appname], I get a "page not found".
So I filled out everything in App-Details but I can't submit my app for review, because:

> Before you can submit your app detail page you must first comply with App Center Guidelines. Please make sure you have specified how your app integrates with Facebook and have met all the requirements. Click here to update your integration.

So I clicked there "to update my integration"
[Image from Settings](http://abload.de/img/error2oii8.png)

The only point I can't fill out is "App Domains". What does it mean?
play.google.com doesn't work.

The page app-details is filled 100%

Answer (score 0):

To make your Facebook app visible, you need to have a Facebook page (or perhaps a link to a web site) for your application, in App Details - Contact Info section. If you don't have it create it following "Create a new Facebook page" link

Comment: I filled everything in the contact info section, Privacy Policy URL, Terms of Service URL, Mail address, User Support URL, Marketing URL

Comment: Did you try to check "Website with Facebook Login" in Basic app settings and add Site URL there?

Comment: Sry, but I can't see the point "website with facebook login" in basic app settings. I postet the link to a screenshot. This is, what I see..

Comment: It is working now. It seems like a Bug if language settings are german. After trying english, I could tick "android".
I am waiting for the review now

Comment: I see my app (link to an external website) clicking on Facebook link https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=... after entering Site url even without it being reviewed by App Center, so maybe you can too